# FileInputStream crashing on .close() NPE

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, file-io

Why is my application crashing? It crashes on the `fis.close();` line.
This is in a `doInBackground` method of an `AsyncTask`.

```
    String collected = null;
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = openFileInput(FILENAME);
        byte[] dataArray = new byte[fis.available()];
        while (fis.read(dataArray) != -1) {
            collected = new String(dataArray);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            fis.close();
            return collected;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

-

```
12-10 14:12:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(701): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-10 14:12:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(701): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-10 14:12:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(701):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
12-10 14:12:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(701):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
12-10 14:12:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(701):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
12-10 14:12:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(701):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
12-10 14:12:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(701):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
12-10 14:12:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(701):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-10 14:12:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(701):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
12-10 14:12:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(701):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
12-10 14:12:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(701):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-10 14:12:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(701): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-10 14:12:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(701):  at com.ollygrov.doughpro.CustomRecipe$loadDatas.doInBackground(CustomRecipe.java:471)
12-10 14:12:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(701):  at com.ollygrov.doughpro.CustomRecipe$loadDatas.doInBackground(CustomRecipe.java:1)
12-10 14:12:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(701):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-10 14:12:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(701):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

Answer (score 1):

Very likely `openFileInput(FILENAME);` is throwing an exception.
This means you are trying to close a `null` stream.
Check for `null` before closing the `InputStream`.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply, I have saved a file using FileOutputStream previously and I'm trying to recall that saved file. Both are the same String. Could it be that the file never saved originally? I'll have to look at this in depth after I finish work, I'll get back to you

Comment: Just take a look at which exceptions you are catching.

Comment: Ok so added a null checker and it is a null stream. Why is it doing this? FILENAME is not null it is a String and a file appears to be created in the save method

Comment: What's the exception thrown while creating the stream? Are you sure you have all the right permissions?

Answer (score 1):

Is there any chance `openFileInput` returns `null`? In such a case, the `NullPointerException` will be silently swallowed at line `byte[] dataArray = new byte[fis.available()];`.

The execution will jump then to the `finally` block, where the exception will be thrown from, as it's not handled in any of the `catch` blocks.

Comment: Thanks, this sheds some light on the process of fis. I'll check up again soon and get back to you. Cheers

Comment: I would suggest using something like Apache Commons IO's `IOUtils.closeSilently()`.  It will basically close any IO stream without throwing an exception at all.